# Ember-cli - should a new project take 30+ mins to generate?

Tags: node.js, terminal, compilation, generator, ember-cli

I come from a Ruby/PHP/Laravel background, and I wanted to come over to the light side, and start working with 1st class JS frameworks - and I've honed in on ember, as it comes with a lot of CLI tools.

When I execute the following:

```
ember new [projectname]
```

Ember goes away for the time it takes to read a Bible before coming back (literally 30+ minutes). I found no errors, it completed the task of scaffolding the project, but it took WAY too long (18mins), and cooks up a project directory with 298MB. There's no way devs are waiting this long to get into a new project. I tried running this from inside a clean VM of Ubuntu 14.04, on a zsh terminal with Node v0.12.13 and NPM 2.15. It appears to be installing node modules - is there a way to speed this up a few orders or magnitude?

Here's a screenshot of where it sits for 98% of this time: http://www.5iveonefour.com/downloads/ember_cli_term.png

I've tried this on my super slow 2010 iMac, and I've had the same result on my new SSD MacBook Pro. What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Well I can't reproduce it. It should maybe take 1 or 2 minutes. But you need a decent bandwidth, so maybe thats your problem? These 300MB needs to get downloaded. There is to mention that npm should have a cache, so the first `ember new` may needs more time. But I strongly recommend you to update to npm 3, this will speed up everything!